# Ember: How to underscore a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

i have a problem using underscored json-data with ember.

```
{"check_lists": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Example-list-1",
        "description": "",
        "status": null,
        "module_actions": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Example-list-1",
        "description": "",
        "status": null,
        "module_actions": []
    }
}
```

The main problem is this error-message:

Error while processing route: checklists No model was found for 'check_list'

Using the following route:

```
Checktouch.ChecklistsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('check_list');
    }
});
```

with the model:

```
Checktouch.Checklist = DS.Model.extend({
    name:                       DS.attr('string'),
    description:                DS.attr('string'),
    status:                     DS.attr('string')
});
```

the module_actions-attribute will be implemented next.

As underscored are not allowed in model-names, i dont know if its even possible to map these underscored json-data to a ember-model.

Does anybody know about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> store.find('check_list')

Can not find the desired model because there is only a `checklist` model. Consequently

> store.find('checklist')

will find your model.

Your next problem is the naming in your JSON data. First solution: you remove the underscore from the JSON data on the server side. Second solution: you write an adapter for your model in ember.

Comment: Thank you, it was quite a good point to research on. After changing the store.find('check_list') to store.find('checklist') i just had to overwrite the extract method of the checklist ChecklistSerializer: extract: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
        payload.checklists = payload.check_lists;
        delete payload.check_lists;
        return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
    } it works so far.